# Equation to find possible combinations of combining lists while retaining order

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations

Lets say I have two ordered lists of size n, `[A1, A2, ..., An]` and `[B1, B2, ...,Bn]`. I want to find all the possible combinations of the two lists where the new lists has `[A1, A2, ..., An]` and `[B1, B2, .., Bn]` in the same order.

So the new list would have `A(p - 1)` before `Ap` and `B(p - 1)` before `Bp`. In simpler terms, `A1` must be before `A2`, `A2` before `A3`, `B1` before `B2`, `B2` before `B3`, and so on.

As an example lets have the two ordered lists be [a, b, c, d] and [1, 2, 3, 4]

```
A few acceptable combinations: [a, b, 1, 2, c, d, 3, 4], [1, 2, a, 3, b, 4, c, d], [a, 1, b, 2, c, 3, d, 4]
A few unacceptable combinations: [b, a, c, d, 1, 2, 3, 4], [a, 2, c, d, b, 1, 3, 4]
```

I found that I can solve this using recursion (python):

```
def combinations (first_list_size, second_list_size):
    if first_list_size == 1 and second_list_size == 1:
        return 2
    if first_list_size == 0 or second_list_size == 0:
        return 1
    return combinations (first_list_size - 1, second_list_size) + combinations (first_list_size, second_list_size - 1)
```

So for the [a, b, c, d] and [1, 2, 3, 4] example the # of possible combinations is 70 (in python `combinations(4, 4)`)

Here is a computed table

```
n combinations
2 6
3 20
4 70
5 252
6 924
7 3432
8 12870
9 48620
10 184756
11 705432
12 2704156
13 10400600
```

I am trying to find a algebraic function to find how many possible combinations, given the restrictions, two lists of n size will have. So f(n)=combinations

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make $2n$ slots in a row and **choose** $n$ of them for the $A$'s. We place the $A$'s in the chosen slots in the right order, and do the same thing with the remaining slots for the $B$'s. The number arrangements  is therefore  $\dbinom{2n}{n}$. This can be rewritten in various ways, such as $\dfrac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$.

Comment: How did you come up with that so quickly? Works like a charm, thanks a million.

Comment: The *Central Binomial Coefficients*  $\binom{2n}{n}$ come up quite often in combinatorics.